# Regular Expression for Ignoring Files that Begin and End with a Sequence

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sftp

I am using Sublime Text 2 and trying to filter out any files that do not begin with a string sequence or end with a string sequence.

Here are some samples with my desired outcome:

```
AAA.123.ZZZ = TRUE
AAA.MY.SPECIAL.FILE.ZZZ = TRUE

ABC.123.ZZZ = FALSE
AAA.123.XYZ = FALSE
/SUBFOLDERNAME = FALSE
FILE NAME WITH WHITESPACE.TXT = FALSE
```

I am using the following expression, but many files are getting by the filter:

```
^(?!AAA\..*\.ZZZ$)[\w\.-]+$
```

I want to include this regular expression in the Sublime Text 2 SFTP configuration under the "ignore_regexes" section.

I realize this is a double negative (using an ignore an inverse match), but I want to be able to replace `AAA` and `ZZZ` so that only files that begin with `AAA.` and end with `.ZZZ` are *included* by Sublime SFTP.

Comment: So what you're actually after is a regex that matches everything *except for* files that start with `AAA` and end with `.ZZZ`? If you can confirm this, I'll answer with a regex that does this : )

Comment: Yes, that is correct, @jeff-escalante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can find something simpler, but the following appears to work:

```
^(?!AAA\.).*|.*(?<!\.ZZZ)$
```

as illustrated in http://rubular.com/r/3yUXh0TOfE

Or, if you need to avoid the negative lookbehind, you can use:

```
^(?!AAA\.).*|.*(?!\.ZZZ).{4}$
```

as illustrated in http://rubular.com/r/VUd3yAQTzl

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working for me. It's possible that Sublime SFTP doesn't support the negative lookbehind. If I switch the Ruby version to 1.8.7, it fails there as well.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, sublime uses python behind the scenes -- this might have something to do with it?

Comment: Hmmm. I checked on Sublime 2 with it's "find" command and it worked as expected. I'm not familiar with Sublime SFTP.

Comment: Ok, I understand now that Sublime SFTP has nothing to do with Sublime 2 (the text editor). Sorry about that.

Comment: See update. I'm not sure if there are other ways to avoid the negative lookbehind.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as the regex is correct. I found a strange workflow issue within Sublime SFTP that will allow me to correctly filter files using this expression, but it will not download or upload because the filter is also applied to the upload action when a local file is changed. Thank you all for the help!